# How to refresh a form after a request?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, servlets, jstl

I've a form that change a value in the database (true->false or false->true).
After the hitting of the button the value is changed, the user is redirected on the same page but the old value showed by the JSTL is still there.

${name}

```
<c:choose>

    <c:when test="${is_active}">

    <form action="deactive.do" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}"/>
        <span style='color:red;'>active</span> - 
        <input type="submit" value="DEACTIVE" name="deactive">
    </form>

    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>

    <form action="active.do" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${id}"/>
        <span style='color:red;'>NOT ACTIVE</span> - 
        <input type="submit" value="ACTIVE" name="active">
    </form>

    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I've tried with adding these lines in the page but didn't worked:

```
<% response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); 
   response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); 
   response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0); %>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a server side problem. Are you looking at the value after it was changed or before? Please paste the code that changes the DB and renders the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to update the values that is being shown by JSTL, may be it is there in session/page/request/application scope. you need to update them as well then JSTL will show updated value

Comment: So awesome! I forogot to update the value of the session variable!